# Ember JS Router - How to produce a 404 Http response code for error page

Tags: ember.js

I'm getting this error when running a SEO audition tool

[image]

I would need to produce something similar to:

[image]

Instead of 404 my error page has a 200 status.

Comment: Are you using [FastBoot](https://ember-fastboot.com/)?

Comment: I've tried to install it but there will be a dependency issue to sort out. I was looking for another way if that's possible. Thanks

Comment: In SPA you don't have such thing as response code

Comment: You need to include more details about your setup. Especially how your ember application is served and what is triggering the 404. Are we talking about a static URL that does not exist or is it a URL containing a dynamic segment (e.g. an ID) and no data exists associated with that dynamic segmet server-side?

Comment: It's just a static URL which doesn't exists.  In the same way if you type www.google.com/non-existent-url. My current error page produces a 200 http status